# What food am I allowed to bring to Austria from Russia?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, russia, austria

Soon I will fly from Russia to Austria. I want to bring a small quantity of food (like one or two boxes of chocolate) to Austria.

In the past there were restrictions on what you could and could not bring to/from Russia. A long time ago, for example, it was not allowed to send a cake from Vienna to Moscow using mail. Later those limitations seem to be lifted (the officials didn't mind me taking a very similar cake on board an airplane to Moscow).

Where can I find out, which food items I am allowed to bring to Austria from Russia in January 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: the quantity of *chocolate* you bring to Austria *for private consumption* is not restricted.

**Long answer**: I looked up the information on the Austrian Ministry of Finance's [website](https://english.bmf.gv.at/customs/travellers/Prohibitions-and-Restrictions-on-Imports.html).
The English version is regretably short but the German [original](https://www.bmf.gv.at/zoll/reise/einfuhrverbote-einfuhrbeschraenkungen/mengenbegrenzungen-lebensmittel.html) states the following:

Basically there are quantity limits for food you bring to Austria, even if it's for private consumption. There is a list with maximal quantities of restricted goods. If you stay within these quantities, you don't need any papers for these goods nor declaring them.

Russia is among "other" countries of origin on this list with the following limitations (for precise wording and explanation of different mentioned food groups, please refer to the German original in [PDF](https://www.bmf.gv.at/zoll/reise/einfuhrverbote-einfuhrbeschraenkungen/2017_02_01_Veterinaerbestimmungen_Waren.pdf?6k0mj8)):

- Baby food: 2 kg
- Meat products, milk, milk products: 0
- Fish products: 1 pcs / 20 kg (with a lot of tiny print in the PDF-file)
- Honey, wax, Gelee Royal, Propolis, pollen: 2 kg
- Eggs: 2 kg
- Special animal food: 2 kg

As you see, nobody cares for your chocolate unless it's mainly made of meat, milk or cheese :)

Comment: Chocolate is made of milk, unless it's a bitter chocolate.

Comment: @Rg7x gW6a cQ3g true, but it's still not a milk (dairy) product.